# Generate html email content using c#

Tags: c#

As a newbie to C# this my attempt generating Html email using c#.Am I doing it the right way? I am sure there are a lot of mistakes. I would really appreciate some help here.

```
class Program // Main class is giving me errors.
    {
        String user = "xyz@abc.com";
        String firstName = "John";
        String lastName = "Doe";

        CreateEmail createEmail = new CreateEmail(toname, toemail, from, ccname, ccemail, body);
        createEmail.Run();
```

Errors:

> - The name 'toname' 'toemail' 'from' 'ccname' 'body' doesnt exist in current 
>     context.
> - 'CreateEmail' does not contain a definistion for 'Run' and no extention method and no extension method accepting a first argument of type could be found ( are you missing a directive or an assembly reference.

here is the class create Email.

```
        String toname;
        String toemail;
        String from;
        String ccname;
        String ccemail;
        String body;
        public CreateEmail(String toname, String toemail, String from, String ccname, String ccemail, string body)
        {
            this.toname = toname;
            this.toemail = toemail;
            this.from = from;
            this.ccname= ccname;
            this.body = body;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(toemail);
            mail.To.Add(ccname);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            mail.Subject = "test email";
            mail.Body = body;
            body = "<div> Hello, this is the body content of the email.</div>";
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");


            try
            {
              client.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in Creating test email ",
                            ex.ToString());
```

Comment: Swap your lines `mail.Boay = body;` and `body = XXXX`.

Comment: _"Am I doing it the right way?"_ - does it work?   Otherwise there is no problem to solve.  [ask].  Good luck

Comment: This should be at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MickyD I have edited the question and listed the errors I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend disposing of your MailMessage after use. And put body = XXX before assignment as Ivien pointed out.

```
try
{
    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.To.Add(toemail);
        mail.To.Add(ccname);
        mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
        mail.Subject = "test email";
        body = "<div> Hello, this is the body content of the email.</div>";
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("localhost");
        client.Send(mail);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in Creating test email {0}", ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I am getting two errors here which are basically related to the main class.

Comment: Please update answer now that OP has provided the missing info

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you are not passing required data in your CreateEmail constructor.
In your example case you need to create string variables and pass them when creating CreateEmail.

```
    String toemail = "xyz@abc.com";
    String toname = "John";
    String from = "Emamr";
    String ccname = "some cc name";
    String from = "some cc email";
    String body = "Some text for mail body";

    CreateEmail createEmail = new CreateEmail(toname, toemail, from, ccname, ccemail, body);
```

The second error is because you are calling method Run() which is not defined anywhere in your CreateEmail class.You have method Execute()

You need to call it like: createEmail.Execute();